# Python: Dictionary as instance variable

Tags: python, class, dictionary, python-3.x

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Least Astonishment” in Python: The Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument)

I'm very confused about the behavior of dictionaries as class instance variables in Python 3.  The way I understand it, instance variables in Python have *per-instance* storage, unlike class variables which are per-class (similar to what some other languages call "static").

And this seems to hold true, except when the instance variable is a dictionary created from a default parameter.  For example:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, values = dict()):
        self.values = values

f1 = Foo()
f1.values["hello"] = "world"

f2 = Foo()
print(f2.values)
```

This program outputs:

```
{'hello': 'world'}
```

Huh? Why does the instance `f2` have the same dictionary instance as `f1`?

I get the expected behavior if I don't pass in an empty dictionary as a default parameter, and just assign `self.values` to an empty dictionary explicitly:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.values = dict()
```

But I can't see why this should make any difference.

Comment: It might be that the default parameters are only evaluated once, when the class is loaded. That way you're merely assigning the same reference as a default parameter.

Comment: Stack overflow has a nice "FAQ" function per tag. Here is the FAQ for the Python tag: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python?sort=faq&pagesize=30 Your question is answered in question number 4.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is a well known surprise in Python. The default parameters are evaluated when the function is defined, not when it is called. So your default parameter is a reference to a common `dict`. It has nothing to do with assigning it to class/instance variables.

If you want to use a default parameter, use `None`, and check it:

```
if values is None:
    self.values = {}
else:
    self.values = values
```

Comment: You'll get the same behavior with a list as well

Comment: You get the same behaviour with *every single* mutable object.

Answer (score 3):

Default values are only evaluated once.  You want something like this:

```
 class Foo:
     def __init__(self, values = None):
         self.values = values or dict()
```

If you supply a `values`, that'll get used.  If not, `values` is evaluated as `FALSE` by the `or` operator and instantiates a new dict.

Comment: This failes if anything falsy is passed as values - e.g. an empty instance of a custom `dict` subclass.